# PHP Curl - Validate and Fetch .csv file efficiently. How?

Tags: php, validation, csv, curl, fetch

I'm very weak in curl functions. I have a script which does hourly routines to update files among networked sites.

I have three concerns:

1. Efficiency
2. Accuracy
3. Security

Having tested it in some length, **it will grab the 404's and save them as csv files**, and then the validation afterward deletes them. But it would be better to reject a non-csv file flat out...even if its disguised as a .csv for malicious purposes.

On that note, I will be saving them to a special folder. Is there any way to hide executable (malicious) code in them? I figured I would keep this directory non-executable to ensure safety.

Here is the code:

```
//check file exists first: 
if ( !$fp = curl_init( $url ) )
    return 'Symbiocard not found at this address ('.$url.'). Please upload manually.';

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1 );
$raw = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
if ( file_exists( $newfile ) ) {
    unlink( $newfile );
} //file_exists( $newfile )
$fp = fopen( $newfile, 'x' );
fwrite( $fp, $raw );
fclose( $fp );

$required_fields = array(
     'symbiostock_site',
    'admin_email',
    'symbiostock_version' 
);
```

I didn't past my validation / file writing code simply because I'd like to filter it on the CURL level.

**THE QUESTION: 
How do I limit curl to only communicate with a genuine csv file (not a 404 or any other document at the supposed .csv location).**

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: HAHA! Silly me. Let me update the post with a more clear question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not limit curl but you can check the response code before you write the file to csv. using `curl_getinfo` you can get full information about you request.

Example

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
    // Nice
} else {
    // Not Nice
}
```

Please note that f you get a `200` response or the mine type or extension is `csv` does not mean it a valid `csv`. You would still need to read each line and validate the content.

Comment: This is helpful. I'll plug that in right away. So really I can abort if a 404 is thrown at me...which is good...but curl can't do any further validation than that?

Comment: Yeap ... you can .. curl is fast and has low memory footprint ... Just about if you don't get `200` and remember to follow links before redirection does not return `200`

Comment: Just a note, this sped things up a little too and removed an error I was dealing with. Great solution thanks.